# How to align text inside a paragraph after a bullet?

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I have to following text inside a `<p>`

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis                         dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus`

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit:

    •   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
    Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
    montes, nascetur ridiculus mus;

    •   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aeneas
    commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
    magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculous mus
```

Like you can see that text below the • is not inline with the text next to the •.

Is it possible inside a paragraph to align/indent all text after a dot?

I know that a list would be much easier to achieve this problem, but I want to know if it is possible without using a list. Why? Because I get this plain text from my API.

I think that it is not possible since I couldn't find anything for this problem, but maybe someone knows how to deal with this?

Comment: Try text replacement and `&nbsp;` for alignments

Comment: This a `ul` and `li` html-tags.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If u get of api plain text, u can use string functions for replace dots on html tags

Comment: @AndreyFedorov What php/javascript function could be used for this?

Comment: @Beer in php str_replace()

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with

```
str_replace("•","<li>", $plain_text);
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Look, I don't know the way how you want to apply this text or what programming language you're trying to get this text, by default ul list are indented.

[ul list](http://jsbin.com/sipoyeyogu/edit?html,css,output)

The reason for this is because the ul contains a display property called list-item by default, if you want to make this list idented is just apply css to format like a ul list. If you not to able to edit with css, if it's a backend language just like c#, java, ruby, python, php etc. What you can make is remove the tags or the dot and separate the paragrafs and output the correct format, if it's a frontend language you can get the content in the ul list and format the text using dom elements, and append this into your page.

I'm learning english, if you not understand, ask for me and I'll answer you.